# Proving that if $x+\frac{1}{x}$ is an integer, then $x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}$ is also an integer for all even $n$ using induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction, alternative-proof, integers

> Prove that if $x+\frac{1}{x}$ is an integer, then  $x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}$
> is also an integer.

I am aware this question has already been answered previously [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043823/x1-x-an-integer-implies-xn1-xn-an-integer#1043850) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742201/prove-if-x1-x-is-an-integer-then-xn1-xn-is-an-integer?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I need help in proving it in an alternative way.

I am first trying to prove this for the case where $n$ is even.

Defining $$I_n:=x^n+\frac{1}{x^n},$$
I noticed that $$\\{\left(x+\frac{1}{x} \right)^n}=x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}{{n\choose k}{\left(x^{n-2k}+\frac{1}{x^{n-2k}}\right)}}$$
$$\Rightarrow I_n=(I_1)^n-\sum_{k=1}^{n/2}{{n\choose k}}\cdot I_{n-2k}$$

I initially planned on proving through induction, i.e., by proving that if $I_n$ is integer for some value of $n$, then $I_{n+2}$ must also be an integer, but for $I_{n+2}$ to be an integer, you also need $I_{n-2},I_{n-4}\ ,...I_{4},I_{2}$ to be integers. How do I mathematically prove that $I_{n}$ being an integer also implies all of these are also integers?

Moreover, would to be correct to instead assume that all $I_n, I_{n-2},I_{n-4}\ ,...I_{4},I_{2}$ are integers for some value of $n$ and ***then*** prove that $I_{n+2}$ is an integer? I ask this because I haven't seen induction proofs assuming the assumption to be true for more than 1 value of the variable.

Comment: are you able to prove that $x^2  + \frac{1}{x^2}$ is an integer?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, individually, I can prove 2, then 4 using 2, and so on....

Comment: Alright, getting there. Use 2 to prove 3...

Comment: @WillJagy But then wouldn't I separately need to prove that for every consecutive even n?

Comment: If you are really intent on proving even $n$  only, you can prove 2, use that to get 4, use 2 and 4 to get 6, use 2 and 6 to get 8.

Comment: "Would to be correct to instead assume that all $I_n,I_{n−2},I_{n−4},...I_4,I_2$ are integers for some value of n and then prove that $I_{n+2}$ is an integer?" Yes, that's a special technique called *strong induction.*

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant how do I prove this for every consecutive integer using a single proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n$ even, observe: $I_n = I_{n-2}\cdot I_2 - I_{n-4}$, [$1$]. Thus you can prove the claim using induction on $n$ being even. Starting with $n = 2$, $I_2 = \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 - 2$ is an integer since $x+\dfrac{1}{x}$ is by assumption. Assume the claim is true for even $n$ up to $n-2$. This means $I_{n-2}, I_{n-4}$ are integers.Then [$1$] says that $I_n$ is also an integer.  Thus by strong induction on even $n$, $I_n$ is an integer for all even $n$.

Comment: This is the first time I'm reading about "strong" induction. Does that allow me to assume the identity to hold up to a given value of n instead of a single value?

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH: It means the claim is true for all indices $k \le n - 2$, the value just before $n$ the one you are trying to prove. So it has to be true for a range of values prior to the one you need to verify to be true too.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^{n+1}+\frac1{x^{n+1}}=\left(x^n+\frac1{x^n}\right)\left(x+\frac1x\right)-\left(x^{n-1}+\frac1{x^{n-1}}\right).$$

Comment: I have already seen this answer. I am trying to prove it through the binomial theorem instead as this fact doesn't come to me naturally at all.

Comment: @WilliamA.Noble"I am aware this question has already been answered previously, but I need help in proving it in an alternative way." Did you even read the entire question? This is A proof by induction, but not the only one.

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing,
let
$u_n
=a^n+b^n
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
u_1u_n
&=(a+b)(a^n+b^n)\\
&=a^{n+1}+ab^n+ba^n+b^{n+1}\\
&=a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}+ab(b^{n-1}+a^{n-1})\\
&=u_{n+1}+abu_{n-1}\\
\text{so}\\
u_{n+1}
&=u_1u_n-abu_{n-1}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
if $ab$, $u_1$ and $u_2$
are integers,
then
$u_n$ is an integer
for $n \ge 1$.

Since
$u_2
=a^2+b^2
=a^2+2ab+b^2-2ab
=(a+b)^2-2ab
=u_1^2-2ab
$,
if
$a+b$ and $ab$ are integers,
then
$a^n+b^n$ is an integer
for $n \ge 1$.

If
$a+\frac1{a}$ is an integer,
then
$b = \frac1{a}$
so
$ab=1$ is an integer,
so
$a^n+\frac1{a^n}$
is an integer for
$n \ge 1$.